# Launcher icon doesn't start MySQL workbench

Tags: 14.04, 14.10, mysql-workbench

I recently upgraded from `14.04` to `14.10` and faced an issue with running queries on MySQL workbench but [this answer on SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26560573/897041) solved it. This answer is about rebuilding the application after patching it's source, I did that successfully. But now I can't start workbench unless I run it from a terminal by running the command `mysql-workbench`

After starting it from the terminal, it's icon appears on the launcher, I right-click it and choose `Lock to launcher`. But after I close the application, and I click the icon to start the application again, it doesn't work !

I click it but nothing happens.

Answer (score 6):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and was in the need of the same thing, so I resolved with this with a couple of easy steps.

I launched MySQL from the command:`mysql-workbench`

I right clicked the icon and locked it to the launcher

In the terminal I ran the following:

```
gedit .local/share/applications/mysql-workbench-bin.desktop
```

I removed the Path which was pointing to `/home/USER`

Finally, I edited the Exec from `mysql-workbench-bin` to `mysql-workbench`

This is the final result:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=MySQL Workbench
Icon=mysql-workbench-bin
Exec=/usr/bin/mysql-workbench
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Mysql-workbench-bin
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

The only thing that I would just make sure that you have the right paths, other than that this should work.

Comment: If it was installed globally, just removing the `.desktop` file from `~/.local/share/applications` would have done the job as well for sure, but you'd have to make sure there is one in `/usr/share/applications`.